# Error while adding a foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>
> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "AB_TRANS_FK3". The conflict occurred in database "DEV", table
>   "dbo.PRODUCT", column 'ID'.

Hello all,

I need your help with this error. I am trying to add a foreign key constraint here using the following query

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AB_TRANS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [AB_TRANS_FK3] FOREIGN KEY([ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PRODUCT] ([ID])
```

Comment: Clearly you have a row in `AB_TRANS` with a foreign key that is not matched by a primary key in `PRODUCT`.

Comment: yes you are right. Is there a way to add the foreign key without validating the existing data?

Comment: the point of a foreign key is to keep data like this consistent. fix the data, don't try and remove the reason for having that foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Check your table to see which row(s) are causing the issue, then you'll need to fix them. This should help:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    dbo.AB_Trans A
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Product P WHERE P.ID = A.ID)
```

If there isn't a match, are you using "0" for the ID or some other dummy value? This could certainly cause the problem as you should be using `NULL` in those cases.

Comment: Actually I just truncated this table dbo.Product because I wanted to reload it but there's a foreign key constraint on the TRANS table on the ID field so thought of dropping the foreign key and then recreating it.